# Footer bg image repeat horizontally across page

Tags: html, css

My bg image for the header works fine but I cant seem to get the footer to stretch across the whole width of the website.  How can I fix this?

```
   body{
background-image: url(images/topbg.jpg), url(images/footerbg.jpg);
background-position: left top, left bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Can you provide us a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YW8H3/

Answer (score 0):

set your body margins and padding to 0:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You just want to stretch your footer background image, here is a simple way to do it:

```
body
{
  background-image: url(images/topbg.jpg) left top repeat-x, url(images/footerbg.jpg) left bottom;
  //Make the Background Image stretched
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to repeat the background image right?
then replace

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

instead of

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

Comment: I DO want to repeat the bg image as it is supposed to stretch across the entire page, I wish i could put a link to the site on here